# Firebase deploy error "page not found This file does not exist ..."

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have created a react app, it's working fine locally. To deploy it in firebase I used `firebase init` and followed the steps then `npm run build` and `firebase deploy`. Now I'm getting this error on the deployed app's home page.

> **Page Not Found**
> This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory. Why am I seeing this?
> You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check your firebase.json and make sure the public directory is pointing to a directory that contains an index.html file.
> You can also add a 404.html in the root of your site to replace this page with a custom error page.

Here is the `firebase.json` file's code.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My build folder path is in the root and looks like this:
[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshoot of your build folder path

Comment: It is in the root. https://imgur.com/a/JWsgbmO

Comment: It looks nice... What url are navigating with?

Comment: It is inside the app called "computers-galore". If it is what you are looking for. `C:\Users\VIVO\Documents\Programming Hero\computers-galore\build`

Comment: Maybe you should check your routes

Comment: I can't find any error related route

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem but now it is working for me.

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "build",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ],
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }]
    }
}
```

Order of Cmd to be executed:

1. firebase init
2. execute npm run build
3. firebase deploy